# How to get nicEdit Text area height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I am using nicEdit for a project, I have a problem as my project is completely dynamic the client wants, when they copy paste any text to the nicEdit text editor the div has to auto resize, for that I need the to find the height of which i am not able to get. I have done a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/vo6g9Lhk/2/)

I have not used any jquery to find the height thinking it might conflict with nicEdit script file

```
<div id="StatusEntry" rows=10 cols=50 contenteditable="true">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</div>
```

This is just the html i have used. Please anyone can help me on this would be thankfull.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use the [`maxHeight` option](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options)?

Comment: i can't because i need to the grab the final height of the div, so i append the value to related div when press save.

Answer (score 0):

you can get div height by using js as like this
var height=$('#StatusEntry').height();

Comment: see this js file.                                             var height=$('#StatusEntry').height();
$div.on('resize',function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#StatusEntry").height(height());
    });

});

Answer (score 0):

```
var height=$('#StatusEntry').height();
$div.on('resize',function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#StatusEntry").height(height());
    });

});``
```